# System.Devices.Aep reference

Tags: .net, bluetooth, namespaces, uwp, .net-assembly

I am working on bluetooth program for windows 10. I have tried tons of different libraries and all the examples don't seem to work entirely on the latest windows 10 except:
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/BluetoothLEClient/cs/Scenario1_DiscoverServer.xaml.cs

And in there is a mysterious line of code that seems to make everything work:

```
string[] requestedProperties = { "System.Devices.Aep.DeviceAddress", "System.Devices.Aep.IsConnected" };
deviceWatcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher("(System.Devices.Aep.ProtocolId:=\"{bb7bb05e-5972-42b5-94fc-76eaa7084d49}\")", requestedProperties, DeviceInformationKind.AssociationEndpoint);
```

However I cannot find the  System.Devices.Aep name space or what assembly it uses. But this code compiles and runs fine. Can anyone tell me what assembly to add to explore the System.Devices.Aep namespace? Thank you

Comment: It seems like this is not a namespace. They are windows properties, please check [windows properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff521659(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Thank you Sunteen, I had stupidly assumed that they would have a .net name space for properties but that makes sense.